# Simplifying something

Tags: python

Is it possible to simplify this in Python?

```
status = get_git_status()   
for s in ("modified", "deleted", "Untracked files:"):
    if s in status:
        pass
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I could simplify that code to simply `status="foobar"`, since that's the only code I can see that has an effect (the setting of a variable).

Comment: Is this really your code? `s in status` will always return `False` here, as you would essentially be doing `if "modified" in "foobar"` and so on...

Comment: assume status is dynamically assigned. i am trying to loop over items in tuple and see if they exist in the dynamically generated string.

Comment: Could you make that clear in your original question then? It's a bit tough to see what you're going for here.

Comment: Your code `if s in status: pass` won't ever do anything, since it either gets skipped, or does nothing by design (thanks to `pass`). It is pointless unless you also have an `else` block.

Comment: i think what you are trying to say here is: `if status in ('modified', ...)                              `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if you need to perform an action for each match or if you're just interested if any of them match.  If your just interested if any of them match, use `any`:

```
if any(s in status for s in ("modified", "deleted", "Untracked files:")):
    whatever()
```

Answer (score 0):

If both "modified" and "deleted" in status, will you run the pass code twice? If you only need to run it once, you can use any():

```
status_list = ("modified", "deleted", "Untracked files:")

if any(s in status for s in status_list):
    pass
```